# Array is in list error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to test if an array contains a certain value and put its index in the variable `p1CombFInd`.

```
int[] allowedNumbers = {
        31,
        32,
        41,
        42,
        43,
        51,
        52,
        53,
        54,
        61,
        62,
        63,
        64,
        65,
        11,
        22,
        33,
        44,
        55,
        66,
        21,
        };

if (Arrays.asList(allowedNumbers).contains(txtNumber2.getText())){
                p1CombFInd = Arrays.asList(allowedNumbers).indexOf(txtNumber1.getText());
}
```

But I always get the error **Cannot resolve symbol "allowedNumbers"**

**Edit:** Could my imports cause the problem, too?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.pexldesign.mia.R.*;
```

Comment: try to use Integer instead of int.

Comment: @ZouZou Java lets us add `,` after last element when we initialize array this way.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this code? Copy and paste the error message and the code it refers to. (And despite what ZouZou says, it's OK to have a comma after the last array element. Some people even prefer to have it.)

Comment: @Pshemo I did'nt said it was the error, it was just a note =)

Comment: I don't see where you can possibly get that error.  I don't see either `allowed` or `numbers` anywhere.

Comment: @SamIam: I don't think a compiler can produce an error like this. It always reports about 1 unfound symbol per error.

Comment: @ZouZou I didn't say you are solving error :) Just pointed that it is not problem :)

Comment: @Pshemo By the way do you know why this is allowed ? I know that the trailing comma in an array initializer is ignored, but why allow this ?

Comment: @ZouZou Probably to allow easier copy-paste process with fragment of data. I sometimes create temporary arrays to check some things and use only few rows of declared arrays `{a,\n b,\n c,\n d,\n e,\n f}`  and it is handy that I can copy entire lines, and don't have to worry about removing comma in last row.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted your search into a method, there's a few issues... for one you're testing `txtNumber2` but then finding `txtNumber1`; second, you're going to search through your numbers twice. Try this instead -

```
public static int getIndex(int[] arr, String value) {
    int v = Integer.valueOf(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == v) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] allowedNumbers = { 31, 32, 41, 42, 43, 51, 52, 53, 54, 61, 62,
            63, 64, 65, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 21, };

    int index = getIndex(allowedNumbers, "65");
    System.out.printf("allowedNumbers[%d] = %d\n", index,
            allowedNumbers[index]);
}
```

Here that outputs

```
allowedNumbers[13] = 65
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work (you can't create a List of ints):

```
Integer[] allowedNumbers = {
        31,
        32,
```

However, here the complete sample:

```
Integer[] allowedNumbers = {
        31,
        32,
        41,
        42,
        43,
        51,
        52,
        53,
        54,
        61,
        62,
        63,
        64,
        65,
        11,
        22,
        33,
        44,
        55,
        66,
        21,
        };
List<Integer> allowedNum = Arrays.asList(allowedNumbers);
int found = allowedNum.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(txtNumber1.getText());
if(found >= 0){
// do something with your number
}
```

This is only for @Martijn Courteaux:

```
System.out.println("int:");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(exInt).size());
for(int[] i : Arrays.asList(exInt)){
    System.out.println(i);
}
System.out.println("Integer-Object:");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(exInteger).size());
for(int i : Arrays.asList(exInteger)){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Will give the following output:

```
int:
1
[I@4631c43f
Integer-Object:
2
1
2
```

Comment: But, I know how the compiler works. This can't be the problem.

Comment: By showing your demo code you included in the answer, you proved that it compiles fine. The OP is facing a compilation error.

Answer (score -2):

I bet the problem is somewhere else. The code you showed us is perfectly fine. It cannot produce that error. Maybe you are putting the array declaration and the code in different files?

**Update:** it looks like this is a message produced by InteliJ IDEA. The compiler will never report an error in that exact form. Try restarting the IDE.

Comment: the answer box is where users look to find an answer to the posted question.  It is not where they look for explanations of what's wrong with the question itself.

Comment: @SamIam: That is right. But there simply is nothing wrong with the code he shows us. And that is what I'm telling him.